# How to set the text or display the text on JButton

Tags: java, loops, text, jbutton

```
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  public class WordGame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements    ActionListener{
   int SkipNum = 0;
    String Get;
    int counter2;
    int score;
   static String words[] = new String[20];
   JButton Button[] = new JButton[5];
   JFrame panel = new JFrame();
   public WordGame() {
    initComponents();
    setWord();
}

public void clear(){
    jButton1.setText("");
    jButton2.setText("");
    jButton3.setText("");
    jButton4.setText("");
    jButton5.setText("");
    jButton6.setText("");
    jButton7.setText("");
    jButton8.setText("");
}

    public void setWord() {
    int index = (int)(Math.random()*20);
    StringBuffer NS = new StringBuffer(words[index]);
    String sh = "";
   Get = words[index];
    int counter = NS.length();
    while (NS.length() != 0) {
        int j = (int)(Math.random() * NS.length());
        sh += NS.charAt(j);
        NS.deleteCharAt(j);

    }
    if (counter == 5){
        for (int i = 0; i < Button.length; i++){
   for (int x = 0; x < 5;x++){
   String Letter = (String.valueOf(sh.charAt(x)));//can't display the letter
   Button[i] = new JButton(Letter);
      Button[i].setText(Letter);
    panel.add(Button[i]);

    }
    }
   jButton6.setVisible(false);
    jButton7.setVisible(false);
    jButton8.setVisible(false);
    }
   else if (counter == 6){

    jButton1.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(0)));
    jButton2.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(1)));
    jButton3.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(2)));
    jButton4.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(3)));
    jButton5.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(4)));
    jButton6.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(5)));
     jButton7.setVisible(false);
    jButton8.setVisible(false);
    }
   else if (counter == 7){

    jButton1.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(0)));
    jButton2.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(1)));
    jButton3.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(2)));
    jButton4.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(3)));
    jButton5.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(4)));
    jButton6.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(5)));
    jButton7.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(6)));
     jButton8.setVisible(false);
    }
   else if (counter == 8){
    jButton1.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(0)));
    jButton2.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(1)));
    jButton3.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(2)));
    jButton4.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(3)));
    jButton5.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(4)));
    jButton6.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(5)));
    jButton7.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(6)));
    jButton8.setText(String.valueOf(sh.charAt(7)));
    }



    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    jButton2.setEnabled(true);
    jButton3.setEnabled(true);
    jButton4.setEnabled(true);
    jButton5.setEnabled(true);
    jButton6.setEnabled(true);
    jButton7.setEnabled(true);
    jButton8.setEnabled(true);

    jTextField1.setText("");

}

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + jButton1.getText());
      jButton1.setEnabled(false);
}             

BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
    int ctr = 0;
    words[ctr] = dataIn.readLine();
    while (ctr < words.length-1){
        ctr++;
        words[ctr] = dataIn.readLine();
    }
```

I'm reading in some characters using a `BufferedReader`, and I want to display each character on a `JButton`. For example, I have on the text file a 5 letter word and I want to display each on the `JButton` "NOTES" on shuffle format. But I cannot display the word or the text.

Comment: Without seeing all the code this is just a stab in the dark, but it is probable that the new JButton objects you are creating aren't immediately visible, so you should probably call setVisible(true) on them. Otherwise, you could try calling validate() to force a redisplay.

Comment: I was looping the JButton but I cant get the letters it loop

Comment: @Fallso setVisible(true) should not be need

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sorry, you are right, I thought they were invisible by default. Not quite sure where I got that from!

Comment: @BlackHusky Can you show all your code?

Comment: However the code posted is not enough to understand the problem, please  post relevant code, remove all irrelevant code... and maybe start by debugging it your self System.out.println() to understand if you enter loop, what are the values ecc... You need to improve this post or it will get closed.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @fallso is it okay ??

Comment: @fallso for counter == 6 , 7 ,8 After I get the code for the 5, I will just make some adjusments and all jbutton 1 - 8 have the same codes

Comment: @Fallso I have posted the code

Comment: @BlackHusky That code doesn't compile.